# NextJS 13 server component fetch not hitting my API endpoint

Tags: next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am using NextJS 13 with the app router.
This is the file structure of my project.

[File Structure Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuBVW.png)

```
async function fetchForm(id: string) {
    const endpoint = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}/api/paymo/${id}`
    console.log("endpoint: ", endpoint);
    const response = await fetch(endpoint, {
        next: { revalidate: 0 }
    });
    return await response.json();
}

const FormPage = async (
    { params }: { params: { id: string } }
) => {

    const id = params.id;
    const data = await fetchForm(id);

    console.log("data: ", data);
```

In my app/protected/paymo/viewer/[id]/page.tsx, I am trying to fetch data from my API.
My NEXT_PUBLIC_URL has been set to http://localhost:3000 and on the console, it prints

`endpoint:  http://localhost:3000/api/paymo/clixw3o9u0005uma24m605z33`

```
export async function GET(
    request: Request,
    { params }: { params: { id: string } }
) {

    const paymoId = params.id;

    console.log(`GET /api/paymo/${paymoId}`);

    console.log("API PAYMO GET");
```

In my app/api/paymo/[id]/route.ts, I am trying to log if the endpoint has been hit.

1. When I render the FormPage component, "API PAYMO GET" is not getting logged. My API endpoint isn't getting hit.
2. Interestingly, when I paste "http://localhost:3000/api/paymo/clixw3o9u0005uma24m605z33" into my browser URL, it prints "API PAYMO GET", and returns the JSON content properly.

How do I fix my FetchForm so that it properly hits the API endpoint?

I pasted "http://localhost:3000/api/paymo/clixw3o9u0005uma24m605z33" into my browser URL, it prints "API PAYMO GET", and returns the JSON content properly. However, fetching content using fetchForm function doesn't work.

Comment: Hi there. Can you post your page.tsx or whatever component is calling using fetchForm?

Comment: `FormPage` is a React Server Component. It only runs on the server, so you can add your API logic directly there.

Comment: Was there a fix for this? I ran into the same issue when making a fetch call from the server. My endpoint works with client side components

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a form submission handler, so its being processed on the client side.

Client Side components do not have access to `process` which is a node.js api.

You can use the exported environment variable `NEXT_PUBLIC_URL` which likely is accessible in the browser at `__URL`. I might think about a more descriptive name than url.

One other way to get the url client side is to use window.location.origin